# spurious "missing sentinel in function call"

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, g++, exec

This simple snippet generates the "missing sentinel in function call" warning with g++ 4.7.0, both if compiled as Cand C++ source. I believe that it's an error of the compiler, as the final `NULL` value is there.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    execlp("mkdir", "mkdir", "-p", "test", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you're wrong.

In C++ NULL is something like `0` or `0L` and might be the same in C. If the type of that constant is smaller than a pointer then it is not safe to pass it to a variadic function, as the high bits will be filled with junk.

On Linux the `execlp(1)` man page says:

> The list of arguments **must** be terminated  by  a  NULL  pointer,  and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast `(char *) NULL`.

i.e. to portably provide the sentinel you need to do:

```
    execlp("mkdir", "mkdir", "-p", "test", (char*)NULL);
```

and this is what GCC is warning you about.

Answer (score 0):

From my [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp):

```
since  these  are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast `(char *) NULL`.
```

Try:

```
execlp("mkdir", "mkdir", "-p", "test", (char*)NULL);
```